# How to make Cargo run tests for local dependencies?

Tags: rust, rust-cargo

I'm working on a project split across multiple crates. The top-level crate (the app) requires the two other crates (libraries) as dependencies. Running `cargo test` in the top-level crate builds the dependencies and runs tests for the top-level crate, but it doesn't run tests for the two other crates. Is there a way to configure `cargo test` so that it will run tests in all three crates?

Thanks!

Comment: I assume that simply changing directories and running cargo from in there isn't a sufficient solution?

Comment: @Shepmaster I want to run the build on CI, so I'd rather be able to execute all commands relative to the top-level source directory. `cd` is my backup plan though.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can pass the `-p` parameter to make Cargo run the tests of a dependency.

So, if your crate is called `sublib`, you can run its tests using:

```
cargo test -p sublib
```

From `cargo test --help`:

> -p SPEC, --package SPEC  Package to run tests for
>
> If the --package argument is given, then SPEC is a package id
>   specification which indicates which package should be tested. If it is
>   not given, then the current package is tested. For more information on
>   SPEC and its format, see the `cargo help pkgid` command.

Comment: Just want to add, this can be used multiple times. For instance, if you want to test the current crate AND the bundled crates, you can do `cargo test -p bundled1 -p bundled2 -p main_crate`